# How to separate cells by string value using GroupBy function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group the rows in my dataframe by spaced string values in one of the columns and create new dataframes for each. An example data frame is below

```
   Conditions   ID
0     x y z     as
1      y z      ad
2       z       aw
3       x       am
```

My expected output is:

Dataframe 1 (Group by x)

```
   Conditions   ID
0     x y z     as
1       x       am
```

Dataframe 2 (Group by y)

```
   Conditions   ID
0     x y z     as
1      y z      ad
```

Dataframe 3 (Group by z)

```
   Conditions   ID
0     x y z     as
1      y z      ad
2       z       aw
```

I've tried using GroupBy, but the spaced string values make it hard to do. For example, x y z would not be grouped with x because they are inherently different strings. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a groupby operation. What you want to do is get the unique "words" from `Conditions` then select the rows containing each word.

```
words = df['Conditions'].str.split(' ').explode().unique()

for w in words:
    print(df[df['Conditions'].str.contains(w)])
```

```
  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
3          x  am

  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
1        y z  ad

  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
1        y z  ad
2          z  aw
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer:

I don't think the `groupby` function alone in pandas is suitable for your needs because it groups by exact matches in a column. However, your scenario requires a search for partial matches in the 'Conditions' column. This requires a different approach.

### Potential Approach

> ***Note:*** This might not be the best way but I think it provides the output you were looking for (unless I am mistaken).

Here's a strategy for achieving this:

1. Identify all the unique conditions (x, y, z, etc.) in your 'Conditions' column. This can be done by splitting each row on space characters to get individual conditions, and then getting the unique conditions.
2. For each unique condition, filter the DataFrame to include only rows where the 'Conditions' column contains that condition. This can be achieved using the `str.contains` function in pandas.

Here's how to do it in code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assume this is your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Conditions': ['x y z', 'y z', 'z', 'x'],
    'ID': ['as', 'ad', 'aw', 'am']
})

# Get unique conditions
conditions = set(condition for sublist in df['Conditions'].str.split().tolist() for condition in sublist)

# Create a dictionary of dataframes, each grouped by a condition
dfs = {condition: df[df['Conditions'].str.contains(condition)] for condition in conditions}
```

The `dfs` variable is a dictionary where each key is a condition and each value is a DataFrame that contains rows where the 'Conditions' column contains that condition. You can access these dataframes using the condition as the key. For example, to get the dataframe for 'x', use `dfs['x']`.

Here's how the resulting dataframes look for the sample data:

For 'x':

```py
print(dfs['x'])

  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
3          x  am
```

For 'y':

```py
print(dfs['y'])

  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
1        y z  ad
```

For 'z':

```py
print(dfs['z'])

  Conditions  ID
0      x y z  as
1        y z  ad
2          z  aw
```

This approach should work for your case. You'll end up with separate DataFrames for each unique condition in your 'Conditions' column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get all the df's in a dictionary. DataFrame 1 is the first key.

```
d = {'DataFrame {}'.format(e):v.drop('g',axis=1) for e,(k,v) in enumerate(df.assign(g = df['Conditions'].str.split()).explode('g').groupby('g'),1)}
```

or

```
{k:df.loc[v] for k,v in df['Conditions'].str.split().explode().reset_index().groupby('Conditions')['index'].agg(list).items()}
```

Output:

```
{'DataFrame 1':   Conditions  ID
 0      x y z  as
 3          x  am,
 'DataFrame 2':   Conditions  ID
 0      x y z  as
 1        y z  ad,
 'DataFrame 3':   Conditions  ID
 0      x y z  as
 1        y z  ad
 2          z  aw}
```